# Button at the border of the screen

Tags: android, android-button

I want to put a button on the left border of a fragment, this last one will be hidden to the right of the screen and only half of the above mentioned button will be shown in its layout. When the button is pressed the fragment will animate to the other side of the screen and half of the button that was initially visible, now it will be hidden showing the other half so the user can reverse the fragment animation. My problem is I don't know how to put the button on the fragment.

[image]

Comment: I already solved my problem, AndroidImageSlider-master is the solution... thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of this is possible in simple code. However if you are fine with complex solutions, you have 2 :

1. you can have your fragment width = screen width + half button width. Initially your fragment would be displayed such that only the extra button width is visible. Then you play a right to left transition animation on it and the other half of button will become visible along with the fragment.
2. You can separate out the fragment and button as two different entities and place them in layout such that thye appear as in Image1. Later when you play the animation on fragment, play it on button as well. The animation properties will stay the same but it will animate 2 views instead of 1.